# Use React App as standalone app and as part of other React App

Tags: reactjs, webpack, architecture, micro-frontend

I have a React app with certain **feature**. Because the feature is big, it was decided to move it to the separate repository. This feature should be deployed as a standalone app and should also be used as a part of other React application. For example as a separate routing page. How can this be implemented? Can this feature be made into a private npm package? And used within other react apps and also be deployed separately? I didn't find such use case. Is it possible with Module Federation of Wepback? Please share some resources.